# Python for Excel: While unique value in column is the same then grab the remaining row data to the right of the column and append to different WS

Tags: python, excel, loops, data-structures, openpyxl

I am somewhat of a beginner to python and have encountered the following problem working with openpyxl. For example I have the sample worksheet below:
[Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1RdO.png)

```
| Boat ID | Emp ID | Emp Name | Start Date | Manager |
------------------------------------------------------
|   1       16044    Derrick      ASAP       Anthony |
|   1       16045    John         ASAP       Anthony |
|   1       16046    Bill         ASAP       Anthony |
|   1       16047    Joe          ASAP       Anthony |
|   2       16048    Justin       ASAP       Jacob   |
|   2       16049    Sandy        ASAP       Jacob   |
|   2       16050    Omar         ASAP       Jacob   |
|   3       16051    Michael      ASAP       Nathan  |
|   3       16052    Bill         ASAP       Nathan  |
```

What I am trying to do is loop through the Boat ID column and while the values of the cell are the equivalent I want to take the respective row data to the right and open a new worksheet/workbook and copy paste rows in Col B:E.

So in theory, for every Boat ID = 1 we would take every row unique to ID 1 from Cols B:E open a new workbook and paste them accordingly. Next, for every Boat ID = 2 we would take the rows with ID = 2 in cols B:E, open a new workbook and paste accordingly. Similarly, we would repeat the process for every Boat ID = 3.

P.S. To keep it simple I have ordered the table by Boat ID in ascending order, but if someone wants bonus points they could opine on how it would be done if the table was not ordered.

Any help here would be appreciated as I am still learning and a complex problem like this would be beneficial to further enhance my skills.

I know I am way off but this is the logic I have so far.

f

[WS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jr0I.png)

Comment: could you please add your worksheet as data in your question (not as image)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used a dictionary in order to categorize all of the boats that I read from the original file according to their "boat id"
the keys were the boats IDs
and the values were the boats

as you can see the code will work even if the original XML file is not sorted by the boat IDs

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("boats.xlsx", read_only=True)
ws = wb.active
boat_dict = {}
for row_index in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
    row = [cell.value for cell in ws[row_index]]
    boat_id = row[0]
    if boat_id in boat_dict:
        boat_dict[boat_id].append(row[1:])
    else:
        boat_dict[boat_id] = [row[1:]]


new_wb=openpyxl.Workbook()
for boat_id , boats in boat_dict.items():
    ws = new_wb.create_sheet(title="Boat id %s"%boat_id)
    for boat in boats:
        ws.append(boat)

new_wb.save("boats_ans.xlsx")
```

hope I could help :)

Comment: Hi Ohad, Could you see the latest version of my question? Instead of opening up new worksheets within a workbook I would like to copy/paste to individual workbooks using an existing template on my PC? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72805494/openpyxl-while-value-in-first-column-is-the-same-append-all-row-data-to-right-o

Comment: do you still need help ?