# Openpyxl: While value in first column is the same append all row data to right of value to new workbook

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops, openpyxl

I have the table below. While the value in the Boat ID column is the same, I would like to copy all data to the right, open up an existing WB on my PC with the same column headers and paste the data starting at cell A2. This process would be repeated for all unique values in the Boat ID column

| Boat ID | Emp ID | Emp Name | Start Date | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16044 | Derrick | ASAP | Anthony |
| 1 | 16045 | John | ASAP | Anthony |
| 1 | 16046 | Bill | ASAP | Anthony |
| 1 | 16047 | Joe | ASAP | Anthony |
| 2 | 16048 | Justin | ASAP | Jacob |
| 2 | 16049 | Sandy | ASAP | Jacob |
| 2 | 16050 | Omar | ASAP | Jacob |
| 3 | 16051 | Michael | ASAP | Nathan |
| 3 | 16052 | Bill | ASAP | Nathan |

I have the code below, but this opens up a new sheet per Boat ID instead of opening an existing WB per Boat ID. Any ideas?

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("boats.xlsx", read_only=True)
ws = wb.active
boat_dict = {}
for row_index in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
    row = [cell.value for cell in ws[row_index]]
    boat_id = row[0]
    if boat_id in boat_dict:
        boat_dict[boat_id].append(row[1:])
    else:
        boat_dict[boat_id] = [row[1:]]


new_wb=openpyxl.Workbook()
for boat_id , boats in boat_dict.items():
    ws = new_wb.create_sheet(title="Boat id %s"%boat_id)
    for boat in boats:
        ws.append(boat)

new_wb.save("boats_ans.xlsx")
```

Comment: This looks like a database export, it would probably make more sense to do the processing on the DB and then pass the results to openpyxl.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what was mentioned and the code, this is what I believe you are looking for...

1. There is an existing file "boats_ans.xlsx" and you want to append data to that file
2. You have no issues creating the data, but you want to create multiple sheets with name "Boat id N" in this boats_ans file
3. The first column should be the header as in the table above and the rest of the rows should contain the data you have there

The below code (only with writing to excel - I have not touched the dictionary creation part) will do this. Note that there should already be a file by that name in your local directory and also if there is an existing sheet with that same name, this code will overwrite it. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
new_wb=openpyxl.Workbook("boats_ans.xlsx") #This will open an existing workbook by name boats_ans
for boat_id , boats in boat_dict.items():
    if boat_id != 'Boat ID': #The dictionary created has a header, so skipping that row
        ws = new_wb.create_sheet(title="Boat id %s"%boat_id) #Your code - new sheet with name as per boat id
        ws.append(["Boat ID","Emp ID","Emp Name","Start Date","Manager"]) # Add header row
        for boat in boats:
            ws.append(boat)

new_wb.save("boats_ans.xlsx") #Save the file
```

**Updates as per new requirements**
Ah, ok. So, you will need to move the create->Save inside the loop, so that a new file will be created each time the loop runs. The same requirements as above still stand, except that now the output will be added to 3 new files (for the 3 different boat_ids). The new files will be named `boats_ans N.xlsx`. Do note that, now, new files are created for each ID instead of updating existing file. As before, only the write-to-excel part of code is here, no change to your dictionary creation part.

```
for boat_id , boats in boat_dict.items():
    if boat_id != 'Boat ID': #The dictionary created has a header, so skipping that row
        new_wb=openpyxl.Workbook() #This will open an existing workbook by name boats_ans
        new_ws=new_wb.active
        new_ws.title = "Boat id {}".format(boat_id) #Your code - new sheet with name as per boat id
        new_ws.append(["Boat ID","Emp ID","Emp Name","Start Date","Manager"]) # Add header row
        for boat in boats:
            new_ws.append(boat)
        new_wb.save("boats_ans {}.xlsx".format(boat_id)) #Save the file
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. In regards to #2 I am actually not trying to create multiple sheets. What I am trying to do is create multiple instances of the boat_ans.xlsx WB with for each unique boat_ID N row data. So ideally for every boat_id = 1 it would open a wb and copy/paste onto the first sheet and close. Then repeat the process for every boat_id = 2.

Comment: @diddlyd43 - Updated code added as new section added at end of response